# UI AlertController - Appears smaller in iPad

Tags: swift, xcode, uialertcontroller, uialertaction

I've added alert controller for accessing camera & files, shown alert using present viewController. Alert view appears correctly on iPhone. But in iPAD, it appears very small randomly on screen.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I've read your question incorrectly, I think, for iPad, the UIAlertController has some issues with presenting well (and sometimes crashing on iPad but showing okay on iPhone).

A `UIPopoverPresentationController` may do the trick.

Taken from [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-create-popover-menus-using-uipopoverpresentationcontroller):

```swift
let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Hello!", message: "This is a test.", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)
present(ac, animated: true)

let popover = ac.popoverPresentationController
popover?.sourceView = view
popover?.sourceRect = CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 64, height: 64)

present(ac, animated: true)
```